# I cannot add a SG in a vpc kubernetes cluster through terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform

I'm using this module in Terraform

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-ibm-modules/cluster/ibm/latest/examples/vpc-kubernetes

However, I can't see any way to introduce a custom security group in this module.

I tried to add this tag `security_group_id` but it does not recognize it. Any idea how to add a security group in this kind of Kubernetes modules?

```
data "ibm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = var.resource_group
}

module "vpc_kubernetes_cluster" {
  //Uncomment the following line to make the source point to registry level
  //source = "terraform-ibm-modules/cluster/ibm//modules/vpc-kubernetes"
  source = "../../modules/vpc-kubernetes"
  cluster_name                    = var.cluster_name
  vpc_id                          = var.vpc_id
  worker_pool_flavor              = var.worker_pool_flavor
  worker_zones                    = var.worker_zones
  worker_nodes_per_zone           = var.worker_nodes_per_zone
  resource_group_id               = data.ibm_resource_group.rg.id
  kube_version                    = var.kube_version
  update_all_workers              = var.update_all_workers
  service_subnet                  = var.service_subnet
  pod_subnet                      = var.pod_subnet
  worker_labels                   = var.worker_labels
  wait_till                       = var.wait_till
  disable_public_service_endpoint = var.disable_public_service_endpoint
  tags                            = var.tags
  cos_instance_crn                = var.cos_instance_crn
  force_delete_storage            = var.force_delete_storage
  kms_config                      = var.kms_config
  taints                          = var.taints
  create_timeout                  = var.create_timeout
  update_timeout                  = var.update_timeout
  delete_timeout                  = var.delete_timeout
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already found that I must add the Security group in the VPC.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).